# How to create general function which can throw any exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have two classes(structure example):

```
public class A {
    protected void doCheck(stuff) throw CommonException, A1Exception{
        if(stuff==1){
            throw new A1Exception(stuff);
        }
        throw new CommonException(stuff);
    }
    public void invokeAstuff(stuff) throw CommonException, A1Exception{
        doCheck(stuff);
    }
}
public class B {
    protected void doCheck(stuff) throw CommonException, B1Exception{
        if(stuff==1){
            throw new B1Exception(stuff);
        }
        throw new CommonException(stuff);
    }
    public void invokeBstuff(stuff, otherStuff) throw CommonException, B1Exception{
        doCheck(stuff);
    }
}
```

"doCheck" methods have same logic for handling stuff, but have 1 different exception which can be thrown by each class: A1Exception for A class and B1Exception for B class

My question is:
How I can write basic class which will implement "doCheck" with common logic + take class of exception that should be thrown in some conditions?
A and B just should extend this class.

Comment: This question is pretty confusing.

Comment: Main idea is left methods: "invokeAstuff" and "invokeBstuff" as is with theirs throw and implement one "generic" function doCheck(stuff)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make a generic abstract class which declares the exception as a generic type, and then make a supplier method which you must override in the subclasses.

```
public abstract class Checkable<X extends Exception> {

    protected abstract X getException(int stuff);

    protected void doCheck(int stuff) throws CommonException, X {
        if (stuff == 1) {
            throw this.getException(stuff);
        }
        throw new CommonException(stuff);
    }

}
```

A subclass would look like:

```
public class A extends Checkable<A1Exception> {

    @Override
    protected A1Exception getException(int stuff) {
        return new A1Exception(stuff);
    }

    public void invokeStuff(int stuff) {
        doCheck(stuff);
    }

}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/pLFF68)

Comment: In this case "invokeStuff" for A class should throw CommonException and Throwable instead of CommonException, A1Exception
I've edited subject, add throw for each invokestuff function

Comment: @YuriyLeonov They could, but it's not required if `CommonException` and `X` are runtime exceptions. It doesn't change the answer at all.

Comment: it's Throwable exceptions

Comment: @YuriyLeonov That's an implementation detail. There's no need to clutter the question further. You can make `invokeStuff` do whatever you want. It's not part of my answer.

Comment: yey! I've found my mistake! I didn't specify A1Exception when I did "extends". Silly my :)